# How to implement Jqgrid with Backbone.js in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Can someone please guide me on how to implement jqgrid with Backbone.js

I have pretty fair knowledge on **jqGrid** as I have used them many times before.

and about **Backbone.js** I have been doing many tutorials on it for more than a week now. I have gone through [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-1/) tutorial for backbone.js.

Now I needed some guidance on how to begin about this.

I tried searching on internet but didn't find any article discussing or explaining this.

Please help me out on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not directly an answer to your question, this may help in dealing with jQuery plugins with Backbone, in general.

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/20/using-jquery-plugins-and-ui-controls-with-backbone/

I've done jQGrid + Backbone on a project once... once... it was not fun, because of the way jQGrid works and tries to do everything for you. You have to give up a lot of control from your Backbone views, and let jQGrid do it for you.

In the end, I ripped JQGrid out and put KendoUI's grid in, instead.